# How to store htest list into a matrix?

Tags: r

I am running the `kpss.test` from package `tseries`. As it is a Hypothesis test, it has the class `htest`. Nevertheless, I want to apply this test to a time series walking through the whole series, but in a specific time frame, applying the kpss test for every time frame and storing the result into a matrix. But, I guess for you to store it into a matrix it must have the same matrix class. But I cannot change the class of the `htest` using `as.matrix` or `as.vector` function, then I cannot store it properly. Someone can suggest anything for me to succeed?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the `broom` package for this.

```
library(broom)
x <- rnorm(1000)  # is level stationary
tidy(kpss.test(x))
```

Comment: Well, broom package seems to be very useful, however it is not available for later R versions. Would have another similar package to indicate?

Comment: What operating system are you using? If you can't install `broom` from CRAN, you can try installing it from GitHub with `devtools::install_github("drgtwo/broom")`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's two options.

First, you could store it in a `list`. Something like

```
save <- list()
for (i in seq_along(timeframes)) {
  save[[i]] <- kpss.test(timeframes[i])
}
```

Second, you could extract the pieces you want and stick them in a matrix.

```
save <- matrix(nrow=length(timeframes), ncol=2)
for (i in seq_along(timeframes)) [
  k <- kpss.test(timeframes[i])
  save[i, ] <- c(k$statistic.KPSS, k$p.value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I could solve it adressing to an empty `data.frame` easily. Thanks!

```
    df <- data.frame(statistic = numeric(0), parameter =  integer(0), p.value = numeric(0), method = character(0), data.name = character(0))
    for (i in 1:3286){
      P_2044050.ts <- ts(P_2044050.df[i:(i+364),])
      kpss_posto <- kpss.test(P_2044050.ts)
      df[i,] <- kpss_posto
    }
```